# Executing different flavors of build in Gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

My app has 2 flavors and each one has a custom env file.

- .mysettings.staged
- .mysettings.production

The debug build of the app works with the correct env file being read depending on the flavor.

When I assemble my release I have the following in the root `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ext {
        defaultEnvFile = file(".mysettings.staged").absolutePath.replace("/android", "")
    }
}
```

This works BUT the problem is that `file(".mysettings.staged")` can either be `staged` or `production` so I want to be able to either:

- detect the flavor and have something like `file(".mysettings.${flavor}")`
- have a wildcard match for the file like `file(".mysettings.*")`
- have an OR statement here

what would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note for clarity that it is not possible to influence properties in the buildscript based on the task run because by the time a task runs it is is too late in the [build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html). Therefore a different approach is needed.

Two possible ways to run different builds flavours for a project are:

1. Pass a project property on the command line, or
2. Setup parallel task hierarchies

##### Pass project property

You can pass [project properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/project_properties.html) on the command line using the `-P` switch and toggle your build flavour that way.

So you can write:

```
buildscript {
    def envFileType
    if (project.hasProperty("flavour") && flavour == 'production') envFileType = 'production'
    else envFileType = 'staged'
    ext {
        envFile = file(".mysettings.$envFileType").absolutePath.replace("/android", "")
    }
}
```

Then `envFile` will normally be the staged version, but if you run Gradle with the argument `-Pflavour=production` you will get the production flavour of the build.

##### Parallel task hierarchy

Passing properties is however not the most robust approach; for one, it will not interact smoothly with Gradle's [incremental build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html) feature without further configuration.

Setting up a parallel task hierarchy for each flavour avoids these problems.

To do this, you need to register both different flavours (staged or production) of each affected task, along with registering the necessary task dependencies, and then Gradle can run the required ones. You can see this approach where builds will have typically have two flavours of each task for "main" and "test" compilations.

Gradle facilitates this approach by providing the [`NamedDomainObjectContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer.html) class which has helpful methods to configure parallel build flavours, one for each object in the container.

###### An example

To show a simple example, you could do something like:

```
/**
 * Define a class with shared functionality
 * The one-argument constructor and name property are required to use
 * a NamedDomainObjectContainer
 */
class BuildFlavour {
    String name

    BuildFlavour(String name) { this.name = name }

    def envFile = ".mysettings.$name"
}

// Use this to create a NamedDomainObjectContainer
def flavours = objects.domainObjectContainer(BuildFlavour)

/**
 * Set up the configuration for each BuildFlavour. You can also do this configuration
 * using methods defined on the task class itself.
 * The configuration is lazy, so it will run when new objects are added to the container
 */
flavours.configureEach { // BuildFlavour is available as "this"
    // Now register all your tasks as before, giving unique names eg
    def fooTask = tasks.register("${name}FooTask") {
        // use env file in task
    }
    tasks.register("${name}BarTask") {
        dependsOn(fooTask)
        // use env file in task
        doLast { println(envFile) }
    }
}

// Add our flavours to the container
flavours.create("staged")
flavours.create("production")
```

Now we can run `stagedBarTask` or `productionBarTask` and we will see printed `.mysettings.staged` or `.mysettings.production` respectively, showing that each task picks up the intended file.

Comment: Very cool! thank you Simon! I think for my requirements the `-Pflavor=` property will be perfect. I will test the parallel task heirarchy though.